# Failed to build modules: libdbusmenu-qt ,libgpg-error, gpgme while building KIO framework

Tags: kde, compiling, qt, libdbusmenu

I am trying to build **KIO framework** using *kdesrc-build --include-dependencies* on Ubuntu 18.04.
Initially everything goes fine, but these 3 modules(**libdbusmenu-qt ,libgpg-error, gpgme**) fails to bulid and compile .
I am getting errors which i am not able to clear out-

```
Building libdbusmenu-qt (26/36)
No source update, but the module has failed to build 5 times in a row
Source update complete for libdbusmenu-qt: no files affected
Preparing build system for libdbusmenu-qt.
Removing files in build directory for libdbusmenu-qt
Old build system cleaned, starting new build system.
Running cmake...
Compiling... failed (after 1 second)

Building libgpg-error (27/36)
No source update, but the module has failed to build 5 times in a row
Updating libgpg-error (to branch master)
Source update complete for libgpg-error: no files affected
Preparing build system for libgpg-error.
Removing files in build directory for libgpg-error
Old build system cleaned, starting new build system.
Unable to configure libgpg-error with autotools

Building gpgme (29/36)
No source update, but the module has failed to build 5 times in a row
Updating gpgme (to branch master)
Source update complete for gpgme: no files affected
Preparing build system for gpgme.
Removing files in build directory for gpgme
Old build system cleaned, starting new build system.
Unable to configure gpgme with autotools
```

> The following modules have failed to build 3 or more times in a row:
>       libdbusmenu-qt,
>       libgpg-error,
>       gpgme
>
> There is probably a local error causing this kind of consistent failure, it
>   is recommended to verify no issues on the system.

How to rectify this problem ?

Comment: You should check the log dir in your `source-dir`. Each failed module will have an error.log with more information.